# What does "weaker for it" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does "weaker for it" mean? Look at this context, for example:

Those of us in the tourism sector have traditionally ignored this reality, and we are weaker for it. Thus, once the members of the relevant population/community have been defined, it is important to identify the values that underlie the kind of tourism they wish to develop for the destination.

Comment: Rephrased, they are weaker because they ignored this reality.

Answer (score 1):

This means "we are weaker because we have traditionally ignored this reality".

Although this is a relatively ordinary construct in English, it is confusing to you because "for" is being used in a slightly old-fashioned way. One is more used to seeing it relate clearly to possession, as in "I bought these flowers for Sarah."

Other examples of "for" used in this way:

She is poorer for her prodigal spending.
(She is poorer because she spends prodigally)

He is all the braver for his suffering.
(His suffering has made him braver)

I am the better for this experience.
(I am better by reason of having had this experience)